# How to increase the precision of numerical derivatives?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerics, numerical-value

I need to make sure about precision of numerical derivatives in my calculations. I use finite element method to obtain a wave function, then I take derivatives of this numerical wave function to get the final answer. These calculations include first derivative, second derivative and square of first derivative.

I get results that are not what I expected, and I guess the problem is due to low precision of numerical differentiating process, but I have no idea how to manipulate it (specifically increase the precision). Does Mathematica consider two side numbers symmetrically? And how can I increase the number of these numbers to increase the precision?

Also, I saw some people suggested `ND` command for numerical differentiation in the old questions, however I checked this command in version 13 and it was undefined.

So I would be grateful if someone can help me. The simplified version of my code is as follows:

```
(* Inputs of system *)
\[Omega] = 0.01;
mp = m = 1836;
me = 1;
M = 1 + mp;
\[Gamma] = 1/2*M*\[Omega];
\[Mu] = (mp*me)/(mp + me);
\[Omega] = SetPrecision[\[Omega], 500];
\[Gamma] = SetPrecision[\[Gamma], 500];
rMin = 10^-16;
rMax = 50.;
n = 20;
meshDisc = 0.001;
AP2 = 1.12519828459293137666567538999147494423581005839162331110151384\
22620106144556634869127789691125460640171721190897392`99.\
69897000433602;
AE2 = 1.12519977871549453890295826441843943502005860489845526171319524\
34122297941598542597828290839372021673697362721938829`99.\
69897000433602;

(******************   FINITE ELEMENT METHOD    *****************)
V[r_] := -(1/r) + 1/2*\[Mu]*\[Omega]^2*r^2;
eqn = -(1/(2 \[Mu])) Laplacian[f[r], {r}] + V[r] *f[r];

{vals, funs} = 
  NDEigensystem[{eqn, DirichletCondition[f[r] == 0., r <= rMin], 
    DirichletCondition[f[r] == 0., r >= rMax]}, f[r], {r, rMin, rMax},
    n, Method -> {"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", \
{"MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> meshDisc}}}}] ;
ns = Position[vals, Min[vals]][[1, 1]];
Er = vals[[ns]];
fr = funs[[ns]];
funR[x_] := funR[x] = fr /. r -> x;

(* densities *)
RhoPlus2[rp_?NumericQ] := ((2 \[Pi]*AP2)/(4 \[Gamma])) (M^2/(
    1 + m)) (Exp[-2 \[Gamma]*rp^2]/rp) NIntegrate[
    funR[r]^2/r*
     Exp[-((2 \[Gamma])/M^2) r^2] (Exp[((4 \[Gamma])/M) rp*r] - 
       Exp[-((4 \[Gamma])/M) rp*r]), {r, rMin, rMax}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 500];

RhoMinus2[
   re_?NumericQ] := ((2 \[Pi]*AE2)/(4 \[Gamma])) (M^2/(
    m^2 + m)) (Exp[-2 \[Gamma]*re^2]/re) NIntegrate[
    funR[r]^2/r*
     Exp[-((2 \[Gamma]*m^2)/M^2) r^2] (Exp[((4 \[Gamma]*m)/M) re*r] - 
       Exp[-((4 \[Gamma]*m)/M) re*r]), {r, rMin, rMax}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 500];

(* first and second derivatives of densities*)
d2e[re_?NumericQ] := (
   2 AE2 E^(-2 re^2 \[Gamma])
     M^2 \[Pi] NIntegrate[(
     funR[r]^2 Exp[-(((2 \[Gamma] m^2) r^2)/
        M^2)] (Exp[((4 \[Gamma] m) re r)/M] - 
        Exp[-(((4 \[Gamma] m) re r)/M)]))/r, {r, rMin, rMax}, 
     WorkingPrecision -> 500])/((m + m^2) re) + (
   AE2 E^(-2 re^2 \[Gamma])
     M^2 \[Pi] NIntegrate[(
     funR[r]^2 Exp[-(((2 \[Gamma] m^2) r^2)/
        M^2)] (Exp[((4 \[Gamma] m) re r)/M] - 
        Exp[-(((4 \[Gamma] m) re r)/M)]))/r, {r, rMin, rMax}, 
     WorkingPrecision -> 500])/((m + m^2) re^3 \[Gamma]) + (
   8 AE2 E^(-2 re^2 \[Gamma])
     M^2 \[Pi] re \[Gamma] NIntegrate[(
     funR[r]^2 Exp[-(((2 \[Gamma] m^2) r^2)/
        M^2)] (Exp[((4 \[Gamma] m) re r)/M] - 
        Exp[-(((4 \[Gamma] m) re r)/M)]))/r, {r, rMin, rMax}, 
     WorkingPrecision -> 500])/(m + m^2) - (
   4 AE2 E^(-2 re^2 \[Gamma])
     M^2 \[Pi] NIntegrate[(
     E^(-((2 m^2 r^2 \[Gamma])/
       M^2)) ((4 E^(-((4 m r re \[Gamma])/M)) m r \[Gamma])/M + (
        4 E^((4 m r re \[Gamma])/M) m r \[Gamma])/M) funR[r]^2)/
     r, {r, rMin, rMax}, WorkingPrecision -> 500])/(m + m^2) - (
   AE2 E^(-2 re^2 \[Gamma])
     M^2 \[Pi] NIntegrate[(
     E^(-((2 m^2 r^2 \[Gamma])/
       M^2)) ((4 E^(-((4 m r re \[Gamma])/M)) m r \[Gamma])/M + (
        4 E^((4 m r re \[Gamma])/M) m r \[Gamma])/M) funR[r]^2)/
     r, {r, rMin, rMax}, 
     WorkingPrecision -> 500])/((m + m^2) re^2 \[Gamma]) + (
   AE2 E^(-2 re^2 \[Gamma])
     M^2 \[Pi] NIntegrate[(
     E^(-((2 m^2 r^2 \[Gamma])/
       M^2)) (-((16 E^(-((4 m r re \[Gamma])/M)) m^2 r^2 \[Gamma]^2)/
         M^2) + (16 E^((4 m r re \[Gamma])/M) m^2 r^2 \[Gamma]^2)/
        M^2) funR[r]^2)/r, {r, rMin, rMax}, 
     WorkingPrecision -> 500])/(2 (m + m^2) re \[Gamma]);
de[re_?NumericQ] := -((
    2 AE2 E^(-2 re^2 \[Gamma])
      M^2 \[Pi] NIntegrate[(
      funR[r]^2 Exp[-(((2 \[Gamma] m^2) r^2)/
         M^2)] (Exp[((4 \[Gamma] m) re r)/M] - 
         Exp[-(((4 \[Gamma] m) re r)/M)]))/r, {r, rMin, rMax}, 
      WorkingPrecision -> 500])/(m + m^2)) - (
   AE2 E^(-2 re^2 \[Gamma])
     M^2 \[Pi] NIntegrate[(
     funR[r]^2 Exp[-(((2 \[Gamma] m^2) r^2)/
        M^2)] (Exp[((4 \[Gamma] m) re r)/M] - 
        Exp[-(((4 \[Gamma] m) re r)/M)]))/r, {r, rMin, rMax}, 
     WorkingPrecision -> 500])/(2 (m + m^2) re^2 \[Gamma]) + (
   AE2 E^(-2 re^2 \[Gamma])
     M^2 \[Pi] NIntegrate[(
     E^(-((2 m^2 r^2 \[Gamma])/
       M^2)) ((4 E^(-((4 m r re \[Gamma])/M)) m r \[Gamma])/M + (
        4 E^((4 m r re \[Gamma])/M) m r \[Gamma])/M) funR[r]^2)/
     r, {r, rMin, rMax}, WorkingPrecision -> 500])/(
   2 (m + m^2) re \[Gamma]);
(* final formula *)
VkEList[re_?
   NumericQ] := -(1/(
    2*me)) ((1/2) (d2e[re] + (2./re) (de[re]))/
      RhoMinus2[re] - (1/4) (de[re]/RhoMinus2[re])^2)
(* table of results *)
mat = Table[{re, VkEList[SetPrecision[re, 500]]}, {re, 5, 25, 20/8}]

ListPlot[mat]
```

Where `funR` is the numerical wane function obtained by FE and `VkEList` is the final function that gives the answers.

**Addendum**

Note that the original formula for `VkEList` is

```
    NUMterm1E[
       r_?NumericQ] := (D[
           RhoMinus2[r2], {r2, 2}] + (2/r2) D[RhoMinus2[r2], r2])/
        RhoMinus2[r2] /. r2 -> r;
    NUMterm2E[r_?NumericQ] := (D[RhoMinus2[r2], r2]/RhoMinus2[r2])^2 /. 
       r2 -> r;
NUMkinE[re_] := -(1/(
     2*me)) ((1/2) NUMterm1E[re] - (1/4) NUMterm2E[re]);
```

where I let Mathematica take derivatives by `D` command, however, it returns `Indetermine` for `re` greater than 5. So I applied `D` commands directly on densities and reached to explicitly functions called `de` and `d2e` here. By the way, it seems that I have no control on precision of differentiation process in this way.
the `de` and `d2e` are

Comment: My advice: start with normal machine numbers. Do not do any of this `SetPrecision` and add "`" around each number to give it specific digits of precision.  i.e. do normal programming with FEM. If the result is not accurate, then you will start looking at why it is not as accurate as you want. You are making things way too complicated when you do these things.  Just my 2 cents.

Comment: I get error message frm NIntegrate: "Numerical integration converging"

Comment: @Nasser Thanks, however I'm not sure your advice works! Please see the addendum.

Comment: [`ResourceFunction["NDerivative"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/NDerivative/?i=NDerivative&searchapi=https%3A%2F%2Fresources.wolframcloud.com%2FFunctionRepository%2Fsearch)